# SQL help joining several tables

Tags: mysql, join

Please can someone help explain how I'd go about building an SQL query for joining the tables in the attached image. I'm new to web & database design and have been struggling with it for days!![tables][1]

http://i44.tinypic.com/9863c0.jpg

The idea behind it is: there can be many shops and many products, each shop can sell the same products as other shops, hence the need for the table named 'shop:product'. I've also factored out the fields size and colour into 2 other tables in order to save on space and improve performance. How do I link it all together so the database server returns the shop name and the products which it sells (including the products size and colour) when I query a particular shop id?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check it out:

```
SELECT s.name, p.name, si.size, c.colour
FROM shops s
INNER JOIN product sp ON (sp.shop_id = s.id)
INNER JOIN products p ON (p.prod_id = sp.prod_id)
INNER JOIN sizes si ON (si.id = p.size)
INNER JOIN colours c ON (c.id = products.colour)
```

example 2:

```
SELECT s.name, p.name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(si.size) AS sizes, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.colour) AS colours
FROM shops s
INNER JOIN product sp ON (sp.shop_id = s.id)
INNER JOIN products p ON (p.prod_id = sp.prod_id)
LEFT JOIN sizes si ON (si.id = p.size)
LEFT JOIN colours c ON (c.id = products.colour)
GROUP BY s.id, p.id
```

Important considerations:

- You should in your table products have size_id and colour_id instead size and colour respectively.
- Not sure if all products have sizes and colours, if not, please consider to switch the inner joins for those two to LEFT JOIN;
- You should change the product table's name for shop_product;
- Tables's name should be on singular not plural (not a obligation);
- You could also group by shop and product and have the colour and size columns concatenated (example. 2)

Comment: Thank you, medina, just what I was looking for. Your first solution worked. :)